# c++ code for send ICMPv6 with neighbor solicitation

Tags: c++, networking, ipv6, icmp

I spend a lot of time with compose ICMPv6 with neighbor solicitation by pcap. I studied RFC:

rfc4861#section-4.3

rfc4443#section-2.3

But I did not be able made correct checksum. As a next step a try tu find some example in C/C++. I found ns.c from http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html and it is not probably good implementaion. Function *sendmsg()* doing segmentation fault and checksum is not correct too ... I think.

If someone know about code, which sending neighbor solicitation,I will be grateful.

If someone one know why code doesn't I will be grateful too.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[ndisc6](https://www.remlab.net/ndisc6/) is a collection of IPv6 diagnostic tools that should give you all the information you are looking for including source code.